# Uploading File Issue In Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

This is my uploadinfg files code in codeigniter application

```
function upload_logo(){
    $ex=$_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
    $epld=explode('.',$ex);
    $filename=date("mdyHis").".".$epld[1];
    $userfile_size=$_FILES['uploadfile']['size'];
    $imggtype=$_FILES['uploadfile']['type'];
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'],"./uploads/".$filename))
        {   
            echo $filename;
        }
    }
```

Here `uploadfile` is the name of the file field.And i have a folder with name uploads in root folder.When i uploading file i got errors.This is working in our server but not working in client's server.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: move_uploaded_file(./uploads/112911224341.docx) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Filename: controllers/pms.php

Line Number: 156
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpvhzCkw' to './uploads/112911224341.docx'

Filename: controllers/pms.php

Line Number: 156
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message states that it's a permissions issue. Ensure that you have the correct permissions set on the the uploads folder. [From the documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html):

> You'll need a destination folder for your uploaded images. Create a
>   folder at the root of your CodeIgniter installation called uploads and
>   set its file permissions to 777.

Comment: yes i have a folder with name uploads in root folder.How can i set its permission to 777?

Comment: @KichuUser: A quick Google search will tell you how to set folder permissions for whatever system you're on (Linux, Windows, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

This error happens due to two reasons.

1. Permission of the folder and invalid group and user owner.
2. Wrong path.

### Permission and owner of folder :

If you are in Linux. Open terminal type this command. This will change the owner of the folder.

```
$ cd project_path && sudo chown -R www-data:www-data picture_folder/
```

Type this command to change the permission of folder.

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 picture_folder/
```

note : Use man command more help about these commands.

```
$ man chmod  OR man chown
```

### Path of folder .

In codeigniter, index.php root file is executed. That is responsible for all activities. So don't use base_url() for root path. Instead. Just give root folder name. like

CI application
  ->

-application

-system

-user_guide

-index.php

-picture_folder

```
  $target_directory="picture_folder/sub_folder";
```

Answer (score 0):

If UBUNTU OS, Then
Go to that folder where you are uploading/keeping 'Uploaded Files', Right Click To That Folder ->Properties -> Permissions Then, Change All 'Access' to create and delete files.

If also, not happening, then go to its parent folder, and follow the same step. I'm sure, you will not get this issue. Because, just now, i got this error. and, i solved like this way only.