# Can't Download a file from a folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, download, file-permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

In codeigniter I can't download a pdf file from a folder. When trying to download it, 
in our server it is working but, in client's server is not working. What can be the reason?

This is my code in controller.

```
$directory = './pdf/';
set_realpath($directory);
$file = $directory.'dwn.pdf';
$fp = fopen($file,'wb');
$pdfcode = "---some texts----";
fwrite($fp,$pdfcode);
fclose($fp);
$data = file_get_contents(base_url()."pdf/dwn.pdf"); // Read the file's contents
$name = 'dwn.pdf';
force_download($name, $data);
```

This is the error.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fopen(./pdf/dwn.pdf) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Filename: controllers/pms.php

Line Number: 732
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: controllers/pms.php

Line Number: 733
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: controllers/pms.php

Line Number: 734
```

Comment: Isn't the error description explains what is wrong?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321275/uploading-file-issue-in-codeigniter  As told you in that answer, did you change your permissions?

Comment: yes i changed the permission to 777

Comment: @Kichu to what? are both the PDF folder and file with the right permission?

Comment: i only changed the permission of folder into 777.Now i change the permission of the file inthat folder to 777.So its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be the file name and/or permisisons, try this modified code

```
$directory = './pdf/';
set_realpath($directory);
$file = $directory.'dwn.pdf';
chmod($file,0777);
$fp = fopen($file,'wb');
$pdfcode = "---some texts----";
fwrite($fp,$pdfcode);
fclose($fp);
$data = file_get_contents($file); // Read the file's contents
$name = 'dwn.pdf';
force_download($name, $data);
```